# How to sort table according to name

Tags: javascript, php, html, sorting, html-table

I have a table I would like to sort in my PHP file:

```
//Table headers
echo "<tr><th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Badge Number</th>";
echo "<th>Category</th>";
echo "<th>Action</th>";
       .
       .
  Some codes
       .
       .

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td id=\"row$count\">$id</td>";
echo "<td>$name</td>"; 
echo "<td>$badge_number</td>";
echo "<td>$category</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"deleteThis($count, $privilege)\"/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Actually I don't think the codes are necessary but I can't seem to figure a way out. I want to sort my table according to NAME. My desired outcome would be whenever I click the "Name" header it would sort the table according to the names in ascending or descending order.

I know that this can be done by javascript but do I have to assign each of the values to an array and use `array.sort` or is that any other better way?

Note: I am new to JavaScript and still learning so if you would like to answer, please do in pure JavaScript codes rather than jQuery as I do not know any jQuery. Please do not suggest any jQuery plugins like "Table Sort" etc.

EDIT: Okay, so let's say I know a bit of jQuery(super beginner level), which I do, what are they way(s) for it to be done?

Comment: If you want to use pure javascript, it is quite painful to code it. that means regenerating the html after you have sorted the elements in your JS. jQuery is a lot easier to pick up than vanilla JS. I first learned jQuery before learning more on javascript. =)

Comment: this is jQueries sweet spot -but if you like pain ...

Comment: Okay, so let's say I know a bit of jQuery, which I do, what are they way(s) for it to be done? Will put it up in the question as edit.

Comment: personally i would just use: https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem in jQuery would be quite simple. Solving it in pure JS would be incredibly complex perhaps impossible. I'd STRONGLY suggest learning jQuery as it is supported by all browsers and extends Javascript in ways you can't imagine. The learning curve is very steep at first but is easy once you learn.
Good site to learn jQuery -> http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/jquery-beginners-1/

In jQuery, you'd simply read the rows and parse them into an associative array (object) with the keys as the value you are sorting on and the values each row. Clear the rows off the table then sort that object by key then add each element of the array as a row to the table.

If your data is coming from a database (doesn't sound like it) then sorting it before display is easiest. If you want the columns to be all sortable, I usually do that with ajax and jQuery but a simple way would be to make each column head be a form submit that then redraws the page - the database code would sort the results each time.

Comment: If you give me example of what [some codes] is, I can write you the jquery.

Comment: I see, my data is coming from a database though. I'm also using ajax. Would it be possible if I were to create a sql query to sort in the database first where by it would be executed if I clicked on the header using a javascript ajax function?

Comment: You are doing ajax without jQuery? You are doing some really hard work if that's true - good luck getting it to work on all flavors of IE along with standard browsers... jQuery's ajax functions are THE BOMB and simple to implement. Anyway, doing the sorting in your sql is BY FAR the easiest way to go. Just clear the table, have ajax fetch the new table and write it to the document (all of this is simple with jQuery and cross-browser compatible).